# Why dpkg asks "Override local changes to /etc/pam.d/common-*?" when libpam-runtime/override is set to false?

Tags: 14.04, server, pam, debconf

In my system, `libpam-runtime/override` is set to `false` (which I can see using `debconf-get-selections`).

Why when upgrading the system, specifically libpam-systemd, dpkg still pops up the window "Override local changes to /etc/pam.d/common-*?"? Should I preseed some other value? I can't find any.

The machine is an Ubuntu 14.04 server.

Answer (score 2):

With Debian Jessie, explicitly setting the libpam-runtime/override value as follows avoided the interactive question during cloud-init:

```
runcmd:
  - 'echo "libpam-runtime libpam-runtime/override boolean false" | debconf-set-selections'
  - 'apt-get update'
  - 'apt-get -y install sssd-ldap'
  - 'systemctl enable sssd'
  - 'systemctl restart sssd'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/682662:

> It is by design of debconf that settings on the system take precedence over any values set in the debconf database.